# Append multiple csv files from different sub-directories into one big file

Tags: python, machine-learning, append, tensor

I am currently building a gesture detection system using a random forest machine learning technique using solar panels. I have 6 different gestures (clockwise, swipe, open fist etc). I have collected data for each gesture from 2 participants. Although, I am struggling to get my head around uploading and organizing the data for my project ready for training, testing, and validation.

Both participants repeated each gesture 30 times. The PicoScope software I used recorded two variables, Time and Voltage. This is all saved within a csv file. Time is a constant in all files, but the voltage changes depending on the gesture being performed above.

I have multiple files, saved within multiple folders. This is how my data is set out:

- I currently have two folders, participant 1, participant 2.
- Within a participants folders are 6 more folders to represent each gesture that they performed
  (clockwise, swipe, open fist etc)
- Within each and every gesture folder are 30 csv files which are 30
  repetitions to that specific gesture
- The csv files then contain two columns, Time and Voltage with 15,007
  data points. The target is classified by the folder it is stored
  under

For example - Participant1/Clockwise/Clockwise_23.csv

I will leave a link to the dataset here: [link dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tpf6uyr9w5te767/AABM_sKRbg7qmMZOwLhFdcoEa?dl=0)

I have never worked with multiple files before for machine learning, I believe i must append all files together before feeding into the machine learning model. I will upload a picture of how I believe this data should look. Left being how the data looks currently, right being how the data should be formatted?
[format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Kltb.jpg)

I have been looking into append, but I have not seen anything near this complexity. I have multiple sub directories. I would like a dataset with all csv files with Time, Voltage and its resultant gesture target. Its gesture target can be found by the folder that it is saved under. Could someone help me with this?

I have managed to append all files together - but currently, all files are being added under the same two headings, leaving me with 5507348 columns. I would like each files data to be identifiable with it's own label. One row for Time, then every files voltage readings beneath, with it's resulting target at the end (folder which the file is saved under)

Comment: Essentially you want to put the file path (e.g. Participant1/Clockwise/Clockwise_23) as the 3 leftmost columns in your output file, followed by the columns already in that file. If you can work out how to enumerate all the files (look at `os.path.walk()`) then you have the values for those 3 columns and also the name of the file to scan. Read each file in turn, prepend the identifying columns, and write out the tagged data to a single file. The `csv` module will handle this quite simply. You will no doubt be told "use `pandas`" but with that much data you might run out of memory, or time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to loop through each subdirectory and join all files into a larger dataframe.

In the code below I start by creating an empty dataframe then walk through 2 layers of subdirectories and then start reading files. This will loop through each only 2 layers of subdirectories and attempt to read all files at that level into a temporary dataframe before concatenating everything into the final complied dataframe.

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

rootpathsting= 'C:\Users\YourName\RootDir'
rootdir = Path(rootpathsting)
level_1_dirs = [f for f in os.listdir(rootdir) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(rootdir, f))]

for l1dir in level_1_dirs:
    print('Dir: ', l1dir)
    l1dirpathstring = rootpathsting + '\\' + l1dir
    l1dirpath = Path(l1dirpathstring)
    level_2_dirs = [f for f in os.listdir(l1dirpath) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(l1dirpath, f))]
    for l2dir in level_2_dirs:
          print('Dir: ', l2dir)
          l2dirpathstring = l1dirpathstring + '\\' + l2dir
          l2dirpath = Path(l2dirpathstring)
          onlyfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(l2dirpath) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(l2dirpath, f))]
          for f in onlyfiles:
                print('File: ', f)
                # I think you want the header of the dataframe to have columns for Time and Channel A and you want to skip reading some other rows... 
                temp_df = pd.read_csv(f, header=1, skiprows=[0, 2, 3])
                display(temp_df)
```

**EDIT**
After this point I assume that `temp_df` looks like this:

```
     Time  Channel A
0    ##    ##
1    ##    ##
2    ##    ##
```

If you want to add file indentification you can add a multi-index to the dataframe like so...

```
temp_df = pd.concat({f:temp_df})

# output:
                           Time  Channel A
anti_clockwise_01     0    ##    ##
                      1    ##    ##
                      2    ##    ##
```

Then you should be able to join all into a single dataframe. I think this will result in a dataframe with 2 indexes(file name and row #), and 2 columns (Time and Channel A).

```
df = pd.concat([df, temp_df], axis=1)
```

Comment: This concatenates all files together into 2 rows. Creating 5507348 columns of data. This isn't what i'm looking for unfortunately. If you look at the question, also the format picture, I would like each files data to be identifiable with it's label. One row for Time, then every files voltage readings beneath, with it's resulting target at the end (folder which the file is saved under).